# EP Plus Rendering Form Controls With Bulk Records Is Slow

Tags: performance, epplus

While I am trying to render Excel report using EP Plus with 500 records and each record has to render 8-10 checkboxes (bool field), then it takes me some 55 seconds to render this report.

The approach I am using is to iterate over each cell and it computes to 500 * 8 = 4000 iterations and it is taking too much time.

Sample code is like:

```
for(int rowCount= 1; rowCount <= 500; rowCount++)
{
  for(int cellCount = 1; cellCount <= 8; cellCount++)
  {
     var uc = sheet.Drawings.AddCheckBoxControl("RowNum_" + rowNum + "_Cell_" + innerCellNo);
     uc.SetPosition(rowNum - 1, 0, innerCellNo - 1, 0);
     uc.Disabled = true;
     uc.Text = ""; 
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to render these many checkboxes (OR form controls) using EP Plus which generates report in lesser time. For example: any bulk load methods like LoadFromDataTable OR LoadFromCollection which I can use to render form controls instead of plain text?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

I tried to render the user controls by writing the for loop and the problem with it is that with higher number of records report generation is too slow.

I was expecting any built in method OR any approach to render the user controls in the report which is better in terms of time it takes to generate the report.